# Is there a way to enable an SQL log to see/optimize my queries using CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I started my test of using a Google's CloudSQL instance with a desktop based application, so far I am impressed with a performance, even it is laggy, it does the job, so my next step is to see what simple modifications can do to my application most intended to reduce Access to the database and optimize if there is something more to do.

How can I do log the sql commands send to the database in order to check what queries are being sent. My app uses ODBC drivers in Windows.

Regards

Comment: Keep in mind that Cloud SQL is meant mostly to be used from other Google Cloud services, such as App Engine or Compute Engine. That way you can minimize your latency between your application and the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is to turn on the [general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html). Unfortunately, that requires SUPER privileges and that was removed some time ago ([announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/-9oscPshaME)). We are going to provide a way to tweak parameters like that via the Cloud SQL API. For now, the best solution is to use a setup a local server and use the logging on that one. If you really want it on production ping us on the google-cloud-sql-discuss Google group and we'll enable the SUPER for your instance.

Comment: Thank you Razvan,  I am testing this configuration as an alternative to host the database locally since we have remote users that do not have a fixed location or connection. Also as a fail over escalable solution so as you suggested I can see what processes are laggy from cloudsql and revise / optimize in local.